# haproxy to deny access based on url and ip addresses

Tags: haproxy

I'm running HAproxy 1.6.8 and want to restrict access to web's admin login with whitelist of IP addresses. But I can't figure out how to do it properly.

```
frontend main
mode http
bind 0.0.0.0:80
acl admin_page path_beg,url_dec -i /admincp
acl whitelist src 10.0.0.0/8
```

My intention is to use:

```
http-request deny admin_page unless whitelist
```

But haproxy check complaints I was incorrect and can't do this.

What's your thought?

Answer (score 2):

```
acl admin_page path_beg,url_dec -i /admincp
```

This might (?) be valid, but if it is... I don't like it. There is too much magic for my taste, passing `*_beg` through a converter.  The following feels like a better, safer solution for this part.

```
acl admin_page path,url_dec -m beg -i /admincp
```

Take the `path` fetch, run it through the `url_dec` (url-unescape) converter, then do a case-insensitive `-i` match of the pattern against the beginning `-m beg` of the resulting string.

Then, you need correct syntax and logic to apply it.

```
http-request deny if admin_page !whitelist
```

The "and" between the two ACLs is implicit, and the second is negated, so deny any request `if` the request matches the `admin_page` ACL and not the `whitelist` ACL.